# OCLint usage example

Tags: objective-c, static-code-analysis

I was looking for an example on how to config OCLint or how to get it running. I made a search but nothing. Here at Stack Overflow there are just 3 posts related, just naming the library and on google just the official [OCLint.org](http://OCLint.org)

The oficial docs says:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ oclint -help
OVERVIEW: OCLint, a static code analysis tool for Objective-C and related languages

USAGE: oclint [options] <input files>

OPTIONS:
  -D <macro>               - Predefine the specified macro
  -F <directory>           - Add directory to framework include search path
  -I <directory>           - Add directory to include search path
  -R <directory>           - Add directory to rule loading path
  -arch <arch_name>        - Specify which architecture (e.g. ppc, i386, x86_64, armv7) the compilation 
                             should targets.
  -help                    - Display available options (-help-hidden for more)
  -include <file>          - Include file before parsing
  -isysroot <directory>    - Add directory to SYSTEM include search path
  -o <file>                - Write output to <file>
  -rc <paramemter>=<value> - Change the baheviour of rules
  -stats                   - Enable statistics output from program
  Choose report type:
    -text                  - Plain text report
    -html                  - HTML formatted report
  -version                 - Display the version of this program
  -x <value>               - Input language type
```

But I would like a better explanation about macro (-D), and which path to choose for -I, -F, -R and what should I point at. A code example as

```
$ oclint path/to/file.m -D something -I something -F something -R something
```

And the output expected from that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you just give `oclint` whatever you give to your compiler.

Alternatively, you may want to try [`oclint-xcodebuild`](https://github.com/oclint/oclint-xcodebuild) if you are not familiar with compiler flags. This is a Python script that extracts flags from your Xcode build log file. See the usage [here](http://docs.oclint.org/en/stable/guide/xcodebuild.html).